# Destroy an Array from Memory

Tags: foxpro, visual-foxpro

How do I destroy an array after I have used it?  My program works great the first time I use it.  The second time I use it, everything gets laggy.

Initializing the array like this:

```
local array MyFiles[1,5]
nFilesFound = ADIR( MyFiles, qazMSG + '*.*')
```

Comment: How are you initializing the array?  Are you using `DIMENSION` or `LOCAL ARRAY`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will remove a variable (including an array) from memory:

```
RELEASE varname
```

Answer (score 1):

It's unlikely that the array already existing is causing a slowdown. More to the point, since you declare the array local, it's released automatically when the routine ends. So your speed problem is something else.